# Javascript change query string for refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, refresh, query-string

I am looking for a way to alter the get query string of an html request using javascript (jquery included) without refreshing the page. This query string would be carried over when refresh. For instance, `http://thissite.site/index.html?id=123` would be the original url, then an event happens and id changes to 235. When the page is refreshed, the refreshed link would be `http://thissite.site/index.html?id=235.`

Answer (score 5):

```
window.location.search = "?id=" + encodeURIComponent(new_value)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/window.location

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: +1 - I didn't know about using the `.search` part of `.location`

Comment: This reloads the page. i only want to change the id for refresh when the user initiates, not for an instant refresh.

Comment: Then use hashes instead, or make it a hyperlink. The browser won't let your code change the URL displayed without actually changing the page displayed; this would be a massive security hole and be exploited by phishers constantly.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 you can use the the following `pushState function`. More info found on [How does pushState protect against potential content forgeries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193983/how-does-pushstate-protect-against-potential-content-forgeries).

I was looking for this as well and saw bandcamp using this for the navigation on http://bandcamp.com/discover