# Weird History.js Security error

Tags: history.js

I get this error in my page.

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure
```

At first, I thought that it was just a matter of Same Origin Policy problem. To test this, I have commented out all the code that deals with History.js

But I still get that error in that page.

It seems that I get this error by simply including jquery.history.js in a page.

Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: See this issue for explanations:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348766/securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-window-history-pushstate

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - apparently I was missing 'www.' from the url I was pushing. It really needs to be exact match - otherwise it won't work. If you want to use both www.example.com and example.com you need to write little helper method for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to pushing state with a URL that is of a different domain name. Check to see you are not using pushState or replaceState with a different domain.