# Three.js: video Texture NeedsUpdate stop rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video

I try to put a video as a texture on a mesh, for that, I tested 2 differents example:

http://jeromeetienne.github.io/threex.videotexture/examples/videotexture.html

and

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Video.html

Both works as expected on the web but it doesn't show anything if I download them from github in local.

If I put

```
videoTexture.needsUpdate = false;
```

then floor and screen are displayed. 
The video is working correctly as I can heard the sound behind but no images are displayed.

Any idea how to resolve this problem ?

(I have tested with both firefox and chromium).

Edit:
in the console of firefox, I have this

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. Three.js:25696:0
Error: WebGL: The canvas used as source for texImage2D here is tainted (write-only). It is forbidden to load a WebGL texture from a tainted canvas. A Canvas becomes tainted for example when a cross-domain image is drawn on it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Cross-Domain_Textures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was completly different than what I thought.

As I was running the file from a local folder and not from the local server, I had the [Same-Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) Problem.

As explain in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042463/1224782