# Why can't history state be changed locally in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a friendly function:

```
var crashBrowser  = function(){

  var total = "";                
  for( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {

      total = total + i.toString();
      history.pushState(0,0, total );

  } 

}
```

On calling `crashBrowser()` when the site runs on `http://` works fine but why is there a problem when called locally with `file://` in the URL

I looked through the JS error , it said `file://` is not supported .I would like to know the reason if there is.

Comment: Well, this is not your function, you got it from one of the "crashxyz.com" sites.

Comment: I suspect this is a situation where the browser is trying to prevent XSS attacks on local files. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13348807/367865

Answer (score 0):

The history editing functions need the website to be accessed via the HTTP protocol, this is due to many security reasons. Opening files locally won't work because they are accesed via the file protocol.