# Which attributes should be changed to allow for image upload via Selenium

Tags: python, image, selenium, upload

**Set-Up**

I'm using Python + Selenium to upload an image to the back-end of a system.

The upload button to which I `send_keys()` has the following HTML,

```
<div id="uploadifive-FileNameUpload" class="uploadifive-button" style="height:
18px; line-height: 18px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; text-align: center;
width: 50px;">
  Upload
  <input id="FileNameUpload" name="FileNameUpload" data-editor="#FileName" 
  data-url="http://also-inc.com/upload/uploadfile" data-path="~/UserFiles/Products/Images/" 
  data-maxsize="10240" data-extensions="*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;" 
  data-thumbnailwidth="128" data-thumbnailheight="128" 
  data-thumbnailpath="/UserFiles/Products/Images/Preview/" data-uniquename="True" 
  data-preview="/Content/uploadify/noimage.jpg" data-isnew="true" 
  data-auth="D2C14774E29BBB87D2F34719884CFC5C6370502B067D5FC55D0C40A5EE6B1646ED4C77C9C0180D607052FF52653BA981732417A24C3F7547903649C4D64491C184E1C60D7756608784B4B3E806417E77750D87BABD9CDDCB6294EA62DE884EC7B3A4416558405874ED1C0259CD4430990BA83FC0" 
  data-session="f1txsiyxglqb3ma1dr45awrf" class="file-uploader hide-input" style="display: none;" 
  type="file">
  <input style="font-size: 18px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; right: -3px; top: -3px; z-index: 999;" type="file">
</div>
```

Note that the button has two `input` with `type="file"`.

---

**Code Used**

```
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[2]')
upload_button.send_keys(path_to_my_image)
```

where `el_id() = browser.find_element_by_id()` and `path_to_my_image` ends with `.jpeg`.

---

**Problem**

The code used successfully uploads the image via the second `input`. The image, however, is saved without the `.jpeg` extension. Thus the image appears broken in the back-end; i.e. `image_name` instead of `image_name.jpeg`.

I think the image is saved without the extension because the second `input` does not allow for it.

---

**Tries**

1. adding an attribute to second `input`

The first `input` has the following attribute `data-extensions="*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;"`. I added this attribute to the second `input`,

```
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[2]')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-extensions','*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.bmp;')", upload_button)
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[2]')
upload_button.send_keys(path_to_my_image)
```

This added the attribute, but the uploaded image was still saved without `.jpeg` extension.

2. changing `class` and `style` attribute of first `input`

The first `input` has `class="file-uploader hide-input"` and `style="display: none;"`, which I set to `class="file-uploader"` and `style="display: block;"` via,

```
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[1]')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','file-uploader hide-input')", upload_button)
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[1]')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','display: block')", upload_button)
upload_button = el_id('uploadifive-FileNameUpload').find_element_by_xpath('input[1]')
upload_button.send_keys(path_to_my_image)
```

but then the image doesn't upload. The upload button changes to a native OS file picker 'Select file' button.

How do I solve this?

---

**Sidenote**

I don't understand why this button has two `input`. I'm a beginner, so forgive me if I'm wrong, but intuitively I think a button just needs 1 `input`?

Comment: You say the file uploads successfully—just without the extension. Where exactly did you see the file? Is the rest of the name correct? That is, is it only the extension that is missing? Are there any other differences? E.g., is it in the same folder as other files uploaded manually (i.e., not with Selenium)?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but are you sure that path_to_my_image contains the file extension?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code attempts seems we can't do much with the second `<input>` tag. But you can simply remove the attribute **style="display: none;"** from the first `<input>` tag and try to invoke `send_keys()` method as follows :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='FileNameUpload' and @name='FileNameUpload']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='FileNameUpload' and @name='FileNameUpload']").send_keys("path_to_my_image")
```

**Note** : **path_to_my_image** must be the *absolute path* of the image file ending with either **.jpg**, **.jpeg**, **.png**, **.gif** or **.bmp** extension and must be less then **10240** bytes.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried your code, but I get: `ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input id="FileNameUpload" class="file-uploader hide-input" name="FileNameUpload" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard`

Comment: @LucSpan For debugging purpose induce some hardcore wait. If that works I will provide the WebdriverWait to wrap up the code. Perhaps `not reachable by keyboard` stems out of mismatch of the binaries you are using interms of _WebDriver_ variant and _WebClient_ variant.

Comment: hardcore wait = `time.sleep()`?

Comment: I've tried 1) `time.sleep(10)` between your first and second line, 2) `time.sleep(10)` between your second and third line, but both give again the not reachable by keyboard error.

Comment: How about your binary versions?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean with 'your binary versions'. I also don't know what you mean with WebDriver and WebClient variants.

Comment: I am asking about _Selenium_ version, _ChromeDriver/GeckoDriver/IEDriverServer_ version and _Chrome/Firefox/IE_ Browser version information and if they are compatible?

Comment: My bad :) Selenium 3.4.3, GeckoDriver 0.19.0, Firefox 59.0.2 (64-bits).

Comment: Can you bump up _Selenium_ to v**3.11.0**, _GeckoDriver_ to v**0.20.0** and re-execute your tests?

Answer (score 0):

In `<input>` tags the text is in the `value` attribute. Setting it with JavaScript should work

```
upload_button = el_id('FileNameUpload')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'arguments[1]';", upload_button, path_to_my_image)
```

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. I ran your code, but got a `JavascriptException: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348766/securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-window-history-pushstate. Not sure how to proceed though.

Comment: @LucSpan just for the fun of it try to use `send_keys` on the hidden field `upload_button = el_id('FileNameUpload') upload_button.send_keys(path_to_my_image)` (without any javascript)

Comment: Already tried that before, gives me an `ElementNotInteractableException: Element <input id="FileNameUpload" class="file-uploader hide-input" name="FileNameUpload" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard`. See original question.

Comment: @LucSpan I see. You can also try another way to make it visible `execute_script("document.getElementById('FileNameUpload'‌​).style.visibility='‌​visible'")`

Comment: This gives an `JavascriptException: SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: @LucSpan try this one `execute_script("document.getElementById('FileNameUpload').style.visibility='‌​visible'")`

Comment: Same. Thank you for your help, I'm going to ask the developer to change the button.

Comment: You can't set the value of a `file` field using JavaScript, regardless of its visibility. As the exception clearly shows, it's a security issue. (If you could set the value with JavaScript, you could trick the browser into uploading any file on the user's system.)