# Replace browser url "http://172.20.30.1:8080" to "http://172.20.30.15:8180" without redirect, using javascript when ajax call return response

Tags: jquery, html

I want to connect from app A with address 
"http://172.20.30.15:8180" to app 2 with address "http://172.20.40.15:8080" that have security OAuth2 and my browser is Firefox. I use ajax for connecting with head
"Bearer token". Pls help me how can display home app B
From app A?

When I use pushstate I catch error, "

ecurityError: The operation is insecure"

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: What about `window.location = 'http://172.20.30.15:8180'` ?

Comment: Tanks a lot but I use firefox. I catch error security and I don't want redirect also I want to change url without pushstate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState` on `ajax success`.

Eg:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "YourURL",
    type: "POST",
    data: "DataIfYouPAss",
    success: function(data) {
        window.history.pushState("YourDetails", "YourTitle", "http://172.20.30.15:8180");
    }
});
```

Comment: Close this question if answer address your question.

Comment: Mr. Shree  thank you for answer but my browser  is Firefox I catch error "ecurityError: The operation is insecure".

Comment: This is not from above code. See this old question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348766/securityerror-the-operation-is-insecure-window-history-pushstate

Comment: Please help me still not fix my problem.